# I have installed PWSH 7 and i want to uninstall 5.1 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, uninstall

I recently installed PWSH (PowerShell) 7 but i had 5.1 and I want to erase it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

> I recently installed PWSH (PowerShell) 7 but i had 5.1 and I want to erase it. How do I do it?

What you want is impossible. PowerShell 5.1 is built-into Windows 10 version 1607+ and cannot be uninstalled.  This also includes Windows 11 21H2.